# Could you help me to print a family tree made with binary search tree?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have begun to learn about binary search tree and I have done an exercise that asks me to make a family tree with a binary search tree.

I have already created it, but I have had some problems with it, so I am not sure if it is correct, and it has four variables: name, surname, father and mother, which make this tree totally different than all examples I have already seen. I will show what I have already done in the code bellow:

```
//I have created a class Ancestor
public class Ancestor {
    String name;
    String surname;
    Ancestor father;
    Ancestor mother;

public Ancestor (String name, String surname){
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    father = null;
    mother = null;
}

public void printAncestor() {
    System.out.println("Ancestors:"+"");
}

public void postOrder (Ancestor a) {
    if (a == null) {
        return;
    }

    else {
        postOrder(a.mother);
        postOrder(a.father);
        a.printAncestor();
    }
  }
}

//Another class familyTree
public class familyTree {
    static Ancestor root = null;

static void insertAncestor (String n, String s){
    Ancestor temp = root;
    Ancestor prev = null;
    boolean notFound = true;

    while (temp != null && notFound){
        if (temp.name.equals(n) && temp.surname.equals(s)){
            notFound = false;
            break;
        }
        else if (n.compareTo(n)<0 && s.compareTo(s)<0){
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp.mother;
        }
        else {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp.father;
        }
    }

    if (notFound){
        Ancestor a = new Ancestor(n, s);
        if (prev == null) {
            root = a;
        }
        else if (n.compareTo(n)<0 && s.compareTo(s)<0){
            prev.mother = a;
        }
        else {
            prev.father = a;
        }
     }
  }
}

//And I have tried to create a family tree in the main class
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// write your code here
    familyTree f = new familyTree();

    f.insertAncestor("Adam", "H");
    f.insertAncestor("Charles", "B");
    f.insertAncestor("Mary", "C");
    f.insertAncestor("Matthew", "W");
    f.insertAncestor("Jane", "X");

 }
}
```

I would like to know if my classes make sense, because they show no error, but they still may be confusing. I would also like to know if I have created the family tree correctly, and based on my method to print the family tree, how would I print it? I have tried it like this:

```
f.postOrder();
```

But it did not work out. So I am not sure about what is the matter. As I said, the fact that the variables (name, surname, father, mother) are different from most of the examples on internet and other materials has made me confused. Anyway, I thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a couple of points.  First of all a small style issue: You'd be better served using more descriptive variable names.  You have a method signature that looks like:

```
static void insertAncestor (String n, String s)
```

Well, `n` and `s` don't make good parameter names.  I can see from the context that `n` is for the name, and `s` is for the surname, but why not just call them `name` and `surname`?

In terms of actual code functionality, this line immediately jumped out at me:

```
else if (n.compareTo(n)<0 && s.compareTo(s)<0){
```

You're comparing `n` and `s` to themselves, so the comparison will **always** result in 0, and that if block will always be skipped, and will fall through to the else block.

What is the desired functionality there?  How are you trying to determine whether or not to go down the mother's side or father's side of the tree?  How would you indicate that "This new Ancestor should be inserted as the root's mother's mother's father's mother"?  It may be the case that a binary tree just isn't the data structure that you should be using in the first place.  Not every data structure is suitable for every problem.

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering. One of my main problems is exactly that, how to compare the parameters, and create the tree in general. I wish the mothers to be at the left, and the fathers at the right, while I will be the root, but I am confused about how doing that. About the data structure used, it is just that the exercise is about binary search tree.

Comment: If the point of the exercise is jot to make a binary search tree, I'd suggest that you change the type of data that you're working with, then.  A family tree just doesn't work well as part of a binary search tree.  The idea of a BST is that each node should be comparable, with a well-defined notion of one node being "greater than" or "less than" another node.  Each node's left child should be less than the node, and the right child should be greater.  None of that makes sense for a family tree.  If you want to use names, maybe have a class list keyed off of each students' scores?

Comment: I agree with you. Thank you for answering me. I will try to adapt it for a more reasonable solution.